# I want to force my decision tree to use specific variables, is it possible?

Tags: r

```
tree = rpart(target~ main_var1+var1+var2+var3
             +var4+main_var2, 
                      data=df, 
                      method = 'anova',
                      control = c(maxdepth = 3, cp=0.00012, minsplit=80, xval=10))
```

I have this code to build a DecisionTree, however it builds it without using main_var1 and main_var2, is it possible to force it to use those variables?

Comment: Please explain *why* would use an algorithm to chooses the best splits while at the same time force it to use worse splits.

Comment: is there other ways to create tree that would use features that you want? @Bernhard

Comment: Again, if you could explain the **Why** chances of a good answer grow much higher, cf.  https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: It could be interesting if main_var1 and main_var2 variables, indicative of events occurring at time 1, before other variables, and other variables representing events or something at time 2. The objective is to compel the decision tree which represents temporal dynamics of variables.

Answer (score -1):

You can write it as

```
ctree(target ~ ., df, controls = ctree_control(maxdepth = 3,  minsplit = 80, maxvar = 10))
```

Comment: In what way does this ensure, that there is a split based on `main_var1`?

Comment: My understanding of the question was the problem is that some variables  (main_var1 and main_var2) doesn't appear in the final decision tree and they wish to see those variables in the final decision tree. Isn't it?

Comment: The OP is apparently unhappy, that `rpart`  at no point decided, that `main_var1` was the right variable to split on. Your proposal is to use `ctree`  instead of `rpart` and I cannot see, how that guarantees splits on specific variables. Please explain in your answer, how this is a solution to "force it to use those variables".